# SSRS comparing two tables - multiple columns against results in one column

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, compare, comparison, subquery

I want to compare staff performance between two tables using SSRS.

Table 1 structure looks as below:

[image]

Table 2 structure looks as below (under each task you see time on task in sec):

[image]

I want to be able to group these results and compare next to each other so it would be displayed as below using SSRS.

Expected output
[image: EmployeeID Task Table1 (s) Task Table2 (s) Difference]

The issue that I have got is that task names in Table1 does not have the same names as in Table2 and when trying to get results side by side I need to use nested query for each task. Query sample below:

```
SELECT Task_Name, SUM(Total_time_spend), CASE WHEN Task_Name = Task1 THEN (SELECT SUM(Task1_1) FROM Table2 ELSE 0 END
FROM Table1
```

I have got around 80 columns in Table2, but can’t think of better way to do this.

From within the SSRS I would ideally want to create separate datasets for Table1 and Table2 and lookup results to be displayed side by side, but I do not know any function that would conditionally return result of different queries. Ideally I would want to avoid having 80 nested queries in my SQL query. Is there any function different than nested IFF is SSRS I could use to conditionally return results of the query based on adjacent column name?

Please let me know if any more info is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: The *real* problem is you have a denormalised design. YOu shouldn't have 80 task columns, there should be 2: `TaskNumber` and `TaskTime`. Fix the design and you'll have a far easier time.

Comment: This would be ideal and definitely it would be something that I would do instead, however table2 is being fed from CSV flat file source and fed through ssis with this design. Alternatively is there any way to convert this design into this structure?

Comment: SSIS has an `Unpivot` transform. You could use this to output the data from the CSV in a normalised structure.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - if I had only knew about this 6 months ago my DB would look totally different... Massive thanks for help you just made my life so much easier! I haven't yet resolved the underlying issue as I need to make some changes to the datasets I am using, but I am confident this will be 10 times easier now. Thanks again!